# HTML editor in Flutter for Web

Tags: flutter, editor

I'm looking for a basic HTML editor for use in a project made with Flutter for web.

There os only one project un Flutter like this specs, it's Zefyr, but It only run un Flutter apps (Android ir iOS) and not in web projects.

Anybody know someone or have any workaround?

I only need a basic usage (not scripting or CSS) to render a few basic HTML tags. (P, b, center, h1, br, ...)

Comment: Have you got any solutions for this? If so can you please share the workaround.

Comment: Sorry, At now I'm using a textfield with multilines, only. I probe some solutions with no lucky. I'm looking for better solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can try my package [html_editor_enhanced](https://github.com/tneotia/html-editor-enhanced) which uses fully native controls with plenty of customization, and works on Flutter Web. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: this plugin has error on build with android on SDK 33